# Update model which having multiple rows

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen, laravel-collection

I have an object model which have multiple rows like result getting with this query:

```
$cities = City::whereIn('id' , [1,2,3])->get();
```

What I want to do is update each row with the same value without using `each` because `each` is making a query on each row, so in above query I will have 3 queries.

Instead of doing this:

```
$cities->each->update(['name' => 'test']);
```

I want to do something like this as I already have the model object, but it doesn't work:

```
$cities->update(['name' => 'test']);
```

Instead I must do something like this to make it work:

```
City::whereIn('id' , $cities->pluck('id'))->update(['Avatar' => 'test']);
```

My question is; Why can't I use this:

```
$cities->update(['name' => 'test']);
```

Comment: `City::whereIn('id' , [1,2,3])->update(['name' => 'test']);`

Comment: I know I can do this but I just illustrate my point by this code, my object is already built in a service and I pass the object to another service to do the update method

Comment: The key to the answer is actually how would you do it without Eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `->get()` method you are getting not a model, but an collection of models.

There is no such thing as multiple row models. Models has only one "row".

Comment: I know that is a collection returned but I just want a way to make the update on the returned object, and I agree with there is no away till now but maybe there is so I asked my question

Comment: you could use laravel macros: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#extending-collections or create static function in model which receives an collection and an update array. In that static function you can iterate trough all cities and update them

Comment: The idea is to not to iterate on all rows if I want this I could use $cities->each... But I think using a macro is a good idea to implement so I'll think about it. but thanks for your help ro

Comment: if you want to do it with one mysql reqyest you have to use `City::whereIn('ID' , $cities->pluck('id'))->update(['Avatar' => 'test']);` in your macro or static function

Comment: I think there is a problem with your solution, as you cannot exact the `ID or id` is your primary key so you need to think about this solution again

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for that in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates):

```
App\Flight::where('active', 1)
          ->where('destination', 'San Diego')
          ->update(['delayed' => 1]);
```

See the **mass update** section.

So, in your case the query must be:

```
City::whereIn('id' , [1,2,3])
    ->update(['name' => 'test']);
```